# Force VS Code to Trigger Autocomplete For Keywords Starting with Non-Alphanumeric Symbols

Tags: intellisense, vscode-extensions

I am trying to make a simple autocomplete for the LSP using:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    const provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('exa', {

        provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext) {
            const completions = [];

            const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.slice(0, position.character);
            if (linePrefix.includes('@')) {
                completions.push(new vscode.CompletionItem("@END"));
                return completions;
            }
        }
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(provider);
}
```

But when I type `@`, no autocomplete is triggered:

[image]

It isn't until I start typing alphanumeric characters that it is triggered. Notice that it seems to actively ignore the `@` sign as part of the autocomplete trigger:

[image]

This is confirmed if the alphanumeric trigger is then selected and an extra `@` sign is added as if the first hadn't even been typed:

[image]

How could I correct this code to accept `@` as part of the autocomplete trigger and completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your code doesn't work.  It may be related to `@` not being a word character in the `exa` language and thus needing to be specifically listed as a trigger character.

Making 2 `CompletionProviders` does work.  Try this code:

```js
// const provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('exa', {
const provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('plaintext', {

        provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {
            const completions = [];

            const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.slice(0, position.character);
            
            let item;
            
            if (linePrefix.startsWith('@')) item = new vscode.CompletionItem("@END");
            if (linePrefix.startsWith('!')) item = new vscode.CompletionItem("!START");
            
            if (item) {
                item.range = new vscode.Range(position.translate(0, -1), position);
                completions.push(item);
                return completions;
            }
        }
    },
   '@', '!'    // list any special characters here
);

context.subscriptions.push(provider);

const provider2 = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('plaintext', {

    provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {
        const completions = [];

        const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.slice(0, position.character);
        if (linePrefix.includes('H')) {
                completions.push(new vscode.CompletionItem("HOWDY"));
                return completions;
        }
    }
});

context.subscriptions.push(provider2);
```

Note: I used `'plaintext'` for my testing so change that.  `provider1` gets called for its list of trigger characters.  `provider2` gets called for regular word characters.

Possibly related to `@` not being a word character is the double `@@END` you were seeing.  I fixed that with

```js
        const item = new vscode.CompletionItem("@END");
        item.range = new vscode.Range(position.translate(0, -1), position);
```

so that the range would include that first `@` character.

[image: completion provider for special characters]

Comment: Listing the special characters at the end and using `item.range = new vscode.Range(position.translate(0, -1), position);` were the key fixes. Thanks!