# Change Character Position for VS Code CompletionItem

Tags: intellisense, vscode-extensions

Extending on the LSP autocomplete [fix from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77546741/130427), I am now trying to get a curly bracket autocomplete where the cursor is in the middle of the curly brackets on completion. This is what I have so far:

```js
const c = new vscode.CompletionItem('@{}');
c.range = new vscode.Range(position.translate(0, -1), position);
completions.push(c);
return completions;
```

But this creates an autocomplete with the cursor at the end of `@{}`. I know I could use

```js
c.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('@{$1}');
```

But that requires pressing tab to return the cursor to a normal typing mode, which is more heavy handed than I would like because the contents of these brackets are small quick comma-separated numbers like `@{0,1}` or `@{1,3}`.

I've seen the simple non-tab completion cursor placing type of autocomplete happen automatically in various VS Code extensions for languages with parentheses and curly brackets. One example is when you start writing a function body using `{` in the Go VS Code extension and the ending `}` is automatically placed after your cursor.

Is there a way for me to simply move the cursor between `@{` and `}` without requiring tab completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `command` to the `CompletionItem` and then run any vscode command after the completion is added.  Try this:

```js
let moveCursorCommand = {};
            

if (linePrefix.startsWith('@')) {
  item = new vscode.CompletionItem("@{}");

  // any title will do, but you must have one
  moveCursorCommand.title = "Move cursor left between brackets";

  // you can also call a command that you have created with registerCommand
  moveCursorCommand.command = "cursorLeft";  // the command ID from Keyboard Shortcuts
}

            
if (item) {
  item.range = new vscode.Range(position.translate(0, -1), position);
  item.command = moveCursorCommand;
  
  ...
}
```

For typescript you could use this:

```js
if (linePrefix.startsWith('@')) {
      
  item = new vscode.CompletionItem("@{}");
      
  const moveCursorCommand: vscode.Command = {
    title: "Move cursor left between brackets",
    command: "cursorLeft"
  };
        
  item.command = moveCursorCommand;
}
```

Or if `moveCursorCommand` is used in more than that one place, it could be higher in the code.

[image: completion with a command to move cursor demo]

Comment: I'm using TypeScript so `let moveCursorCommand = {};` is a no-go. I'm getting `Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'. ts(2339)` followed by `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Command': title, command ts(2739)`. Any suggestions for making this code fully typed and TypeScript compatible? `new vscode.Command` does not see not seem to correspond to a type as I would expect.

Comment: I added some typescript code at the end of the answer.